# Use of atomic reference in Effective Jave example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In Effective Java - Item 74 Joshua Bloch demonstrates safe use of parameterless constructor with separate initialization method in following code snippet.

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
            private int x, y; // Our state
                    // This enum and field are used to track initialization

            private enum State {
                NEW, INITIALIZING, INITIALIZED
            };

            private final AtomicReference<State> init = new AtomicReference<State>(
                    State.NEW);

            public AbstractFoo(int x, int y) {
                initialize(x, y);
            }

            // This constructor and the following method allow
            // subclass's readObject method to initialize our state.
            protected AbstractFoo() {
            }

            protected final void initialize(int x, int y) {
                if (!init.compareAndSet(State.NEW, State.INITIALIZING))
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialized");
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                // ...Do anything else the original constructor did
                init.set(State.INITIALIZED);
            }

            // These methods provide access to internal state so it can
            // be manually serialized by subclass's writeObject method.
            protected final int getX() {
                checkInit();
                return x;
            }

            protected final int getY() {
                checkInit();
                return y;
            }

            // Must call from all public and protected instance methods
            private void checkInit() {
                if (init.get() != State.INITIALIZED)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Uninitialized");
            }

        }
```

What puzzles me is use of `AtomicReference`. His explanation sounds:

> Note that the initialized field is an atomic reference
>   (java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference). This is necessary to
>   ensure object integrity in the face of a determined adversary. In the
>   absence of this precaution, if one thread were to invoke initialize on
>   an instance while a second thread attempted to use it, the second
>   thread might see the instance in an inconsistent state.

I fail to understand how this strengthens the object safety against using it in inconsistent state. In my understanding, if one threads runs `initialize()` and the second one runs any of accessors, there cannot be a situation when
the second would read the value of the x or y field  without initialization being marked as completed.

Other possible issue I might see here is that `AtomicReference` should be threadsafe (probably with volatile field inside). This would ensure immediate synchronization of value change in the `init` variable with other threads which would prevent getting `IllegalStateException` when in fact the initialization has been done but the thread executing accessor methods cannot see it. But is this the thing the author is talking about?

Is my reasoning correct? Or is there other explanation to this?

Answer (score 9):

This is a long answer, and it sounds like you already have some grasp of the issue, so I'm adding headers to try and make it easier for you to fast-forward past the parts you already know.

## The problem

Multithreading is a bit tricky, and one of the trickier bits is that the compiler/JVM is allowed to **reorder** operations across threads in the absence of synchronization. That is, if thread A does:

```
field1 = "hello";
field2 = "world";
```

and thread B does:

```
System.out.println(field2);
System.out.println(field1);
```

Then it's possible that thread B would print out "world" followed by "null" (assuming that's what `field1` was initially). This "shouldn't" happen, because you set `field2` after `field1` in the code — so if `field2` has been set, then surely `field1` must be, too? Nope! The compiler is allowed to reorder things so that thread 2 sees the assignments as happening like this:

```
field2 = "world";
field1 = "hello";
```

(It could even see `field2 = "world"` and *never* see `field1 = "hello"`, or it could never see either assignment, or other possibilities.) There are various reasons why this could happen: it might be more efficient due to how the compiler wants to use registers, or it could be that it's a more efficient way to share memory across CPU cores. Point is, it's allowed.

### ... even with constructors

One of the more un-intuitive concepts here is that a constructor generally doesn't provide any special guarantees for reordering ([except, it does for `final` fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)). So don't think of the constructor as anything other than a method, and don't think of a method as anything other than a grouping of actions, and don't think of an object's state as anything other than a grouping of fields. It seems obvious that an assignment in a constructor would be seen by anyone who has that object (after all, how can you read an object's state before you finished making the object?), but that notion is incorrect due to reorderings. What you think of as `foo = new ConcreteFoo()` is actually:

- allocate memory for a new `ConcreteFoo` (call it `this`); call `initalize`, do some stuff...
- `this.x = x`
- `this.y = y`
- `foo = <the newly constructed object>`

You can see how the bottom three assignments could be reordered; thread B could see them as happening in various ways, including (but not limited to):

- `foo = <the newly constructed object, with default values for all fields>`
- `foo.getX()` which returns `0`
- `this.x = x` (possible a long time later)
- (`this.y = y` is never seen by thread B)

## Happens-before relationships

However, there are ways to solve that problem. Let's put the `AtomicReference` to the side for a moment...

The way to solve the problem is with a a **happens-before** (HB) relationship. If there is a HB relationship between the writes and the reads, then the CPU is *not* allowed to do the reordering above.

Specifically:

- if thread A does action A
- and thread B does action B
- and action A happens-before action B
- then when thread B does action B, it must see *at least* all of the actions that thread A saw as of action A. In other words, thread B sees the world at least as "up to date" as thread A saw it.

That's pretty abstract, so let me make it more concrete. One way you can establish a happens-before edge is with a `volatile` field: there's a HB relationship between one thread writing to that field and another thread reading from it. So, if thread A writes to a `volatile` field, and thread B reads from that same field, then thread B must see the world as thread A saw it at the time of the write (well, *at least* as recently as that: thread B could *also* see some subsequent actions).

So, let's say `field2` were `volatile`. In that case:

```
Thread 1:
field1 = "hello";
field2 = "world"; // point 1

Thread 2:
System.out.println(field2); // point 2
System.out.println(field1); // point 3
```

Here, point 1 "starts" a HB relationship that point 2 "finishes." That means that as of point 2, thread 2 must see everything that thread 1 saw at point 1 — specifically, the assignment `field1 = "hello"` (as well as `field2 = "world"`). And so, thread 2 will print out "world`\n`hello" as expected.

## AtomicReferences

So, what does all this have to do with `AtomicReference`? The secret lies in the javadoc for the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package:

> The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles, as stated in section 17.4 of The Java™ Language Specification.

In other words, there is a HB relationship between `myAtomicRef.set` and `myAtomicRef.get`. Or, as in the example above, between `myAtomicRef.compareAndSet` and `myAtomicRef.get`.

## Back to `AbstractFoo`

Without the `AtomicReference` actions, there are no HB relationships established in `AbstractFoo`. If one thread assigns a value to `this.x` (as it does in `initialize`, called by the constructor) and another thread reads the value `this.x` (as it does during `getX`), you could have the reordering problem mentioned above, and have `getX` return the default value for `x` (that is, `0`).

But `AbstractFoo` *does* take specific measures to establish HB relationships: `initialize` also calls `init.set` *after* it assigns `this.x = x`, and `getX` calls `init.get` (via `checkInit`) *before* it reads `this.x` to return it (similarly with `y`). That establishes the HB relationship, ensuring that thread 2 calling `getX`, by the time it reads `this.x`, sees the world as thread A saw it at the end of `initialize`, when it called `init.set`; specifically, thread 2 sees the action `this.x = x` before it performs the action `return [this.]x`.

## Further reading

There are a few other ways to establish happens-before edges, but that's out of scope for this answer. They're listed in [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4).

And the obligatory reference to [JCIP](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/), a great book for multithreading issues in general, and their applicability to Java in particular.

Answer (score 0):

At the one hand, the AtomicReference provides happens-before mechanism, that's why any thread will get fully initialized object after one thread invokes `init.set(State.INITIALIZED);` and the thread, querying an accessor, calls `init.get()`.
At the other hand, `compareAndSet` works atomically, that's why only one thread and only once can run initialization. As a bonus: java atomic primitives are non-blocking, that's why not just `synchronized`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem appears if you try create an instance with the non-arg constructor and call the "initialize" method from one thread and try to use a method from the object (like getX()) from a different thread. Without the AtomicReference, it could be possible that the "checkInit" method could throw the exception even if the object was properly initialized because it cannot be ensured that the change to "state" is visible across threads. AtomicReference syncronizes the access to "state" so any method can get the appropriate value.

So, as a summary, you're right in that the accessors cannot work if "initialize" doesn't run, but it is still possible that the accessors throw the exception if the AtomicReference is not used.